# Prevent line path from overflowing graph in svg using D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am following this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

But when I replace `area` in `focus` with `line`, it doesn't work properly anymore. Zooming, panning, and using brush make the `line` path overflow the left and right boundaries of the graph, like this:

[image: 1]]

This is the screenshot of the main chart, i.e. `focus`, only. It doesn't include the `context` chart

This problem doesn't happen with the `area` element like in the example code. I guess I don't make appropriate updates in `brushed()` and `zoomed()`. What should I do to prevent the overflow?

Here are the changes I made to use `line`:

Original code:

```
var area = d3.area()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

[...]

focus.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);

[...]

function brushed() {
  [...]
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  [...]
}

function zoomed() {
  [...]
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  [...]
}
```

My code:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

[...]

focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

[...]

function brushed() {
  [...]
  focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  [...]
}

function zoomed() {
  [...]
  focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  [...]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have another problem somewhere else, because simply changing the area generator to a line generator **does** work: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/14b389e74d1eb783f24a892fa2c30b4b

Comment: Voting to close until you share a code which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing clip path, that is hiding data outside chart domain. It's all in the example you're using.

CSS:

```
.area {
    fill: steelblue;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
```

JS:

```
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```